# Milo OPC UA - unable to connect to server from client when server restarts. server is set to 'USER_TOKEN_POLICY_USERNAME'

Tags: milo

I am having milo opcua server with `USER_TOKEN_POLICY_USERNAME` enabled and used `UsernameIdentityValidator` to set username and password.

From milo client side, I have used `UsernameProvider` to set `setIdentityProvider`.

When I run this setup everything works fine.

But when I restart opcua server, milo client won't reconnect. I'm getting below exception:

> [milo-shared-thread-pool-2] Skipping validation for certificate: C=DE, ST=" ", L=Locality, OU=OrganizationUnit, O=Organization, CN=AggrServer@7aaf488fd8d6

> 29.01.2021 09:25:48.282+0000 INFO  [m.o.serv.KafkaConsumer(1bc715b8)] [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] Sent record successfully to topic : NSCH_TEST_Data.
> 29.01.2021 09:26:55.681+0000 WARN  [o.e.m.opcua.sdk.client.SessionFsm] [milo-shared-thread-pool-3] [2] Keep Alive failureCount=4 exceeds failuresAllowed=3
> 29.01.2021 09:26:55.681+0000 WARN  [o.e.m.opcua.sdk.client.SessionFsm] [milo-shared-thread-pool-3] [2] Keep Alive failureCount=5 exceeds failuresAllowed=3
> 29.01.2021 09:26:55.682+0000 INFO  [m.o.MiloConnectorRemote(7b76b59d)] [milo-shared-thread-pool-6] opc.tcp://192.168.56.101:4840: onSessionInactive: OpcUaSession{sessionId=NodeId{ns=1, id=Session:fc6fdb4f-0e8a-441d-ba25-45d067d434e7}, sessionName=OpcUa@0b8bc292754c}
> 29.01.2021 09:26:55.682+0000 INFO  [m.o.MiloConnectorRemote(7b76b59d)] [milo-shared-thread-pool-6] opc.tcp://192.168.56.101:4840: sessionInactive: OpcUaSession{sessionId=NodeId{ns=1, id=Session:fc6fdb4f-0e8a-441d-ba25-45d067d434e7}, sessionName=OpcUa@0b8bc292754c}
> 29.01.2021 09:26:55.682+0000 INFO  [m.o.MiloConnectorRemote(7b76b59d)] [milo-shared-thread-pool-6] opc.tcp://192.168.56.101:4840: notify Observer-opc.tcp://192.168.56.101:4840 about ConnectionEvent(state=Connecting, prevState=Connected, label=opc.tcp://192.168.56.101:4840)
> 29.01.2021 09:26:55.683+0000 INFO  [m.opcua.OpcUaObserverImpl(754d0f4a)] [milo-shared-thread-pool-6] Observer-opc.tcp://192.168.56.101:4840: handle the event ConnectionEvent(state=Connecting, prevState=Connected, label=opc.tcp://192.168.56.101:4840)
> 29.01.2021 09:26:55.683+0000 INFO  [m.o.OpcUaObserverImpl$ModelReadyChangeChecker(3dd6dea0)] [milo-shared-thread-pool-6] OpcUaObserverImpl-opc.tcp://192.168.56.101:4840: stop
> 29.01.2021 09:26:55.683+0000 INFO  [m.opcua.OpcUaObserverImpl(754d0f4a)] [milo-shared-thread-pool-6] Observer-opc.tcp://192.168.56.101:4840: notify 2 listeners about ModelUnavailableEvent@1791022155[uri=opc.tcp://192.168.56.101:4840,nodesCount=0,label=Observer-opc.tcp://192.168.56.101:4840]
> 29.01.2021 09:26:55.683+0000 INFO  [m.opcua.OpcUaObserverImpl(754d0f4a)] [DefaultDispatcher-worker-1] Observer-opc.tcp://192.168.56.101:4840: notify Subscriber-opc.tcp://192.168.56.101:4840 about ModelUnavailableEvent@1791022155[uri=opc.tcp://192.168.56.101:4840,nodesCount=0,label=Observer-opc.tcp://192.168.56.101:4840]
> 29.01.2021 09:26:55.683+0000 INFO  [opcua.MiloSubscriber(364cd1b9)] [DefaultDispatcher-worker-1] Subscriber-opc.tcp://192.168.56.101:4840: unsubscribe 1 subscriptions
> 29.01.2021 09:26:55.683+0000 INFO  [m.opcua.OpcUaObserverImpl(754d0f4a)] [DefaultDispatcher-worker-2] Observer-opc.tcp://192.168.56.101:4840: notify SyncProcessor-opc.tcp://192.168.56.101:4840 about ModelUnavailableEvent@1791022155[uri=opc.tcp://192.168.56.101:4840,nodesCount=0,label=Observer-opc.tcp://192.168.56.101:4840]
> 29.01.2021 09:26:55.683+0000 INFO  [m.opcua.serv.SyncProcessor(2474528)] [DefaultDispatcher-worker-2] SyncProcessor: ignore the event ModelUnavailableEvent@1791022155[uri=opc.tcp://192.168.56.101:4840,nodesCount=0,label=Observer-opc.tcp://192.168.56.101:4840]
> 29.01.2021 09:26:55.686+0000 INFO  [opcua.MiloSubscriber(364cd1b9)] [DefaultDispatcher-worker-1] SyncExecutor-Subscriber(364cd1b9)-opc.tcp://192.168.56.101:4840: SyncExecutor-Subscriber(364cd1b9)-opc.tcp://192.168.56.101:4840: unsubscribe, subscriptionId=1
> 29.01.2021 09:26:55.686+0000 INFO  [opcua.MiloSubscriber(364cd1b9)] [DefaultDispatcher-worker-1] Subscriber-opc.tcp://192.168.56.101:4840: delete subscription SyncExecutor-Subscriber(364cd1b9)-opc.tcp://192.168.56.101:4840(SyncExecutor-Subscriber(364cd1b9)-opc.tcp://192.168.56.101:4840)
> 29.01.2021 09:27:11.685+0000 WARN  [opcua.MiloSubscriber(364cd1b9)] [DefaultDispatcher-worker-1] [Subscriber-opc.tcp://192.168.56.101:4840: deleteSubscription(1) of SyncExecutor-Subscriber(364cd1b9)-opc.tcp://192.168.56.101:4840] return null, because of UaException: status=Bad_ConnectionRejected, message=io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: /192.168.56.101:4840
> 29.01.2021 09:27:27.703+0000 WARN  [o.e.m.o.s.c.s.ClientCertificateValidator$InsecureValidator] [milo-shared-thread-pool-5] Skipping validation for certificate: C=DE, ST=" ", L=Locality, OU=OrganizationUnit, O=Organization, CN=AggrServer@7aaf488fd8d6
> 29.01.2021 09:27:31.782+0000 WARN  [o.e.m.o.s.c.s.ClientCertificateValidator$InsecureValidator] [milo-shared-thread-pool-2] Skipping validation for certificate: C=DE, ST=" ", L=Locality, OU=OrganizationUnit, O=Organization, CN=AggrServer@7aaf488fd8d6
> 29.01.2021 09:27:39.806+0000 WARN  [o.e.m.o.s.c.s.ClientCertificateValidator$InsecureValidator] [milo-shared-thread-pool-6] Skipping validation for certificate: C=DE, ST=" ", L=Locality, OU=OrganizationUnit, O=Organization, CN=AggrServer@7aaf488fd8d6
> 29.01.2021 09:27:55.830+0000 WARN  [o.e.m.o.s.c.s.ClientCertificateValidator$InsecureValidator] [milo-shared-thread-pool-3] Skipping validation for certificate: C=DE, ST=" ", L=Locality, OU=OrganizationUnit, O=Organization, CN=AggrServer@7aaf488fd8d6

NEW LOGS

> 02.02.2021 18:32:55.541+0000 WARN  [opcua.MiloSubscriber(3c5d9688)] [DefaultDispatcher-worker-3] [Subscriber-opc.tcp://192.168.56.101:4840: deleteSubscription(1) of SyncExecutor-Subscriber(3c5d9688)-opc.tcp://192.168.56.101:4840] return null, because of UaException: status=Bad_ConnectionRejected, message=io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: /192.168.56.101:4840
> 02.02.2021 18:32:55.542+0000 INFO  [opcua.MiloBrowser(1d141b2d)] [DefaultDispatcher-worker-2] idNameTypeSet.nodes.size
> 02.02.2021 18:32:55.542+0000 INFO  [m.o.OpcUaObserverImpl$ModelReadyChangeChecker(3c8bf12c)] [DefaultDispatcher-worker-2] OpcUaObserverImpl-opc.tcp://192.168.56.101:4840: exit model checking, because stopped externally
> 02.02.2021 18:33:59.790+0000 INFO  [m.o.MiloConnectorRemote(74c9951c)] [milo-shared-thread-pool-3] opc.tcp://192.168.56.101:4840: onSessionActive: OpcUaSession{sessionId=NodeId{ns=1, id=Session:d27e7db7-4401-4f08-8c17-7bfaf9075fe4}, sessionName=OpcUa@154c9f72aa09}
> 02.02.2021 18:33:59.790+0000 INFO  [m.o.MiloConnectorRemote(74c9951c)] [milo-shared-thread-pool-3] opc.tcp://192.168.56.101:4840: notify Observer-opc.tcp://192.168.56.101:4840 about ConnectionEvent(state=Connected, prevState=Connecting, label=opc.tcp://192.168.56.101:4840)
> 02.02.2021 18:33:59.790+0000 INFO  [m.opcua.OpcUaObserverImpl(ff09afd)] [milo-shared-thread-pool-3] Observer-opc.tcp://192.168.56.101:4840: handle the event ConnectionEvent(state=Connected, prevState=Connecting, label=opc.tcp://192.168.56.101:4840)
> 02.02.2021 18:33:59.790+0000 INFO  [m.o.OpcUaObserverImpl$ModelReadyChangeChecker(3c8bf12c)] [milo-shared-thread-pool-3] OpcUaObserverImpl-opc.tcp://192.168.56.101:4840: start
> 02.02.2021 18:33:59.790+0000 INFO  [m.o.OpcUaObserverImpl$ModelReadyChangeChecker(3c8bf12c)] [milo-shared-thread-pool-3] OpcUaObserverImpl-opc.tcp://192.168.56.101:4840: modelReadyChecking=MinMaxInterval(min=10, max=30, timeUnit=SECONDS, current=10, step=3), modelChangeChecking=MinMaxInterval(min=60, max=1800, timeUnit=SECONDS, current=60, step=180), modelReadyMinNodesCount=0
> 02.02.2021 18:33:59.804+0000 INFO  [m.o.OpcUaObserverImpl$ModelReadyChangeChecker(3c8bf12c)] [DefaultDispatcher-worker-2] OpcUaObserverImpl-opc.tcp://192.168.56.101:4840: -> check(modelReadyMinNodesCount=0,modelChangeCheckingRunning=false)
> 02.02.2021 18:33:59.804+0000 INFO  [opcua.MiloBrowser(1d141b2d)] [DefaultDispatcher-worker-2] In nodesCount method
> 02.02.2021 18:33:59.817+0000 INFO  [opcua.MiloBrowser(1d141b2d)] [DefaultDispatcher-worker-2] nodesCount=3605

Comment: This isn’t an exception and isn’t related to whatever is causing it not to reconnect. You’ll have to provide more information or logs.

Comment: just added '.setIdentityProvider(UsernameProvider(getSystemEnv("USERNAME"), getSystemEnv("PASSWORD")))' to client part and it stopped working

Comment: "onSessionActive:" was not getting triggered

Comment: You'll have to provide more logs or a Wireshark capture or something.

Comment: @KevinHerron added few more logs

Answer (score 0):

Seems there is an issue with client/server certificate validation.

UA PKI, X509 and other is complex and hard to understand and even harder to configure properly, can't answer this with few words. If you are just starting with OPC UA, try to skip server policies and user identification until you have learned about.

Server and client will need certificates in order the decrypt or encrypt the user authentification.

But do some checks:

- Check, if the client has the server certificate in its trusted path.
- Check, if the server certificate has altered. The server should not regenerate its self signed certificate with each server start, but only with installation setup or administration.

Workarounds:

- Disable client and/or server security checks if possible
- Use another security profile, e.g. http://opcfoundation.org/UA/SecurityPolicy#None, but then you may not use user identification policies.

Answer (score 0):

I think the meaningful Exception to extract from your new logs is this:

```
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: /192.168.56.101:4840
```

Simple networking error. The server isn't there, isn't running, a firewall is in the way, etc...

It's not anything you're doing wrong in client code right now.

Comment: ran same code without authentication feature. client reconnects to server even after getting above netty exception. added logs for reference(above)

Comment: Can you get a Wireshark capture? Most of these logs are from your application, not Milo, and they don't help me much.

Comment: Let me give you few more details, I am running this in a docker environment. 
when milo client connects to millo server in docker environment its seems that on a reconnect its picking up the container id as endpoint URI. 
we noticed this on debugging. would sure this creating a problem. On first connect it picks server IP (192.168.56.101:4840) on restart it picked container ID 
This are just my observations. I would like to know if my deduction could be a reason it does not connect

Comment: Maybe. Are you trying to force it to reconnect instead of allowing it to do so on its own? There’s no reason it would do discovery and choose a new endpoint URL if you were letting it reconnect on its own.